# 'Employees' does not contain an identity column

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to reseed my table column but getting error

> 'Employees' does not contain an identity column

I have checked my table and it does have an ID column.

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL, 
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL, 
    [MiddleName] [nvarchar](max) NULL, 
    [LastName] [nvarchar](max) NULL, 
    [Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
```

Comment: What are the definitions of the table? Are you sure that the `ID` column is an identity?

Comment: Just because you name a column "ID" does not mean it is defined as an identity column.

Comment: Please show the table structure.  Just because a column is named `ID` doesn't make it an identity.

Comment: Yes I checked, but can you please tell me how to check maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: `SP_COLUMNS Employees`, the value of `TYPE_NAME` should be `int identity` (assuming it is an int)

Comment: You can also right-click your table in SQL Server Management Studio and choose "Script Table as -> CREATE To -> New Query Editor Window".

Comment: "it does have an ID column." A column named "ID" is not an identity column. RTFM time - "tsql create table identity" and google

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees](
 [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [MiddleName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [LastName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the column as the [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) column, it is not assumed/implicit.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees]
  ([ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
  -- rest of columns
```

Comment: It worked after Identity set yes from column property. Thanks